# openapi-generator -l typescript-angular not working

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install, openapi-generator, openapi.net

I am issues while generating angular code run using the openapi-generator for language `typescript-angular` any idea how to fix it? I even tried `openapi-generator help meta` `-l` is a valid option, not sure why I am getting the below error when I run the below command in angular terminal

command using: `openapi-generator generate -i <WebAPI_Swagger_EndPoint> -l typescript-angular -o ./angular --config angular.conf` eg, WebAPI_Swagger_EndPoint: https://test/swagger/v2/swagger.json

Error: `[error] Found unexpected parameters: [-l, typescript-angular]`

`See 'openapi-generator-cli help' for usage`

Version using: 4.3.1

Any help or options available? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please use `-g` instead to specify the generator name

e.g.

```
openapi-generator generate -i <WebAPI_Swagger_EndPoint> -g typescript-angular -o ./angular --config angular.conf
```

Comment: thank you, @William Cheng, I tried with -g it worked but was wondering why -l was not working it used to before.

Comment: "-g" refers to generators, which is more accurate compared with "-l", which refers to languages (and some generators are not languages such as protobuf-schema converter)